# Using directive controller methods in the template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Say I have this directive:

```
app.directive('person', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.sayHi = function() {
                console.log('hi');
            }

            this.sayBye = function() {
                console.log('goodbye')
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        },
        template: '<p ng-click="sayHi()">Hello</p>'
    }
});
```

If the element is clicked the `sayHi()` will be called, as it is attached to the `$scope`, but the `sayBye` method would not work

**My questions:**

1. Is the only way to call a controller method from the template
   achieved by attaching it to the $scope?
2. If so, doesn't this run the
   risk of colliding with other directive functions that could be also
   attached to the scope in the same way or does each directive have its own scope?
3. Is the only reason to attach
   methods to `this` to allow other directives access to those methods
   via `require`?

I'm assuming it's best to keep directive logic encapsulated where possible, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the only way to call a controller method from the template achieved
>   by attaching it to the $scope?

Yes. Scopes are the proxies between templates and JavaScript.

> If so, doesn't this run the risk of colliding with other directive
>   functions that could be also attached to the scope in the same way or
>   does each directive have its own scope?

Yes, that risk is there, but scopes are defined like a tree of parent and child scopes, where the first one found (searching from the current scope upward) applies. Hopefully this scenario explains what I'm trying to say:

- **Root scope**
- name = "Johnny"

  - **Child**
  - name = "Jenny"

    - **Grand child**
    - name = "Jonas"

When the grand child scope is attached to a template with `{{ name }}`, the result will be `Jonas`, similarly, when the child scope is attached to a template with `{{ name }}`, the result will be `Jenny`.

Whether or not a directive creates a scope, is determined by its `scope` property. See the [Angular documentation on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for details on that.

> Is the only reason to attach methods to this to allow other directives
>   access to those methods via require?

Exactly, you're passing a constructor function and by using `this.foo = function () {}` you are defining a function on the instance, and that instance is shared with everyone that requires it. As a side note, keep in mind the difference between `this.foo = function () {}` and `Foo.prototype.foo = function () {}` in performance-sensitive situations!